# Good practice do add long-lasting data to db in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to develop and deploy my first ruby application. During this process I've created certain tables in the data base without associated model.
For example, the user roles table. Despite it may be better to use model and add data there by web interface, it's not the subject of the question, the table may be with the list of cities or some other data.
  The initial population is clear, this work is done with "rake db:seed". 
  But what if I need to add more data to this table? What is the best practice?
Certainly, seed-file should be filled with the new data. But I have already this table with the data in production. How to add this new data there? 
The only answer that comes to me in mind is to use plain SQL. But it seems not to be a "rails way".
Thank you.

Update.
As natural continuation, not only new data creation is needed, but also updating and deleting already existent data.

Comment: So you don't want to make an admin interface for your cities table? In that case it would be an option to use the Rails console.

Comment: I've heard it's dangerous do it at least because I may have a lot of production servers besides the development one. And if I make a mistake during this repeated action? No, some automation is absolutely nesessary.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. What do you mean by new data? E.g. you have a list of cities and want to add a city to the list? Something like that?

Comment: Exactly. And, maybe, update or delete existing city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make seeds.rb insert a new record only when it's not existed. For example

```
cities = [
  { :name => 'New York'},
  { :name => 'Paris' },
  { :name => 'Tokyo' },
  { :name => 'Saigon' }]
cities.each do |city|
  City.create(city) unless City.exists?(:name => city[:name])
end
```

Comment: Nice idea, but... It does not help to update and delete. Maybe I should write it in question in more precise way, but, of course, the whole CRUD access in needed.

Comment: If Japan government decide to rename Tokyo, I'll be in trouble with offered approach :)

Comment: That seems to be an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
cities.each do |city|
  City.find_or_create_by_name(city[:name])
end
```

This will fire query to check for record and it does not exist it will create one. Does the same work when using unless but as mentioned we are going by "Rails Way".